# Individual col searching, datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Ok, I have the code working, but for some reason it is not filtering any of the results. It always returns zero found, even though the search I do is there. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var oTableData;
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tdata;

    $('#filterrow').hide();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DataTable.aspx/GetData",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {

            tdata = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);

            oTableData = $("#tblDataTable").DataTable({
                data: tdata,
                responsive: true,
                dom: '<"top"Tfl><"clear">rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
                tableTools: {
                    "sSwfPath": "/Content/DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                    "aButtons": [
                        {
                            "sExtends": "copy",
                            "sButtonText": "Copy to clipboard",
                            "oSelectorOpts": { page: 'current' }
                        },
                        {
                            "sExtends": "csv",
                            "sButtonText": "Export to CSV",
                            "oSelectorOpts": { page: 'current' }
                        }
                    ]
                }
                columns: [
                    { data: 'Amount' },
                    { data: 'MessageDate' },
                    { data: 'Status' },
                    { data: 'MessageId' }
                ]
            });

            var table = oTableData;
            table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
                $('input', table.column(colIdx).footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    table
                        .column(colIdx)
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I've taken from this site:

http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

**UPDATE **

If I use individual id searches it works:

```
$('#dtreference').on('keyup', function () {
    oTableData
        .columns(0)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
});
```

** UPDATE **

Ok, so adding a bit of logging has revealed the following. On the initial draw of the table, I have 7 columns 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

When I enter a value into the first column, the logging reveals the following:

1,2,3,4,5,6

I'd still expect this to search / filter the table.

Comment: Are you hitting your DataTable.aspx/GetData method?
That URL doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Yep. getting the data is fine. I just need to filter it.

Comment: Looks like a closure issue to me... `colIdx` might not be what you think it is.

Comment: you can also check out my yadcf plugin for datatables http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/

Comment: Hi Daniel, this looks good. Can you apply the filters to the footer, instead of the headers?